# Adding 3 new derived fields from from the where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, field

I have following query,

```
select *
from   (select a.id
              ,a.dt
              ,a.bal_desc
              ,c.bal_cd
              ,c.bal_amt
              ,row_number() over (partition by b.id order by b.prd_id desc, b.event desc) as rnum
        from   tbl_a a
              ,tbl_b b
              ,tbl_c c
              ,tbl_d d
        where  a.id = b.id
        and    a.dt = b. dt
        and    c.cd = d.cd
        and    a.id = c.id
        and    a.dt = c.dt
        and    a.dt = 10222020
        and    cn_dt is null
        and    ev_cd = 'X'
        and    pgm_cd = 'X'
        and    wrk_tp_cd in ('1','2','3'))
where  rnum = 1;
```

When I run the above query, the resulting population is incorrect. Each instance of the `a.ID` should have a `c.Bal_Amt` value. Can someone help me understand why when I run the `WRK_TP_CD` separately, I get 3 different population sizes that are more close to the expected population than when I run all 3 of them together.

Also, I was hoping someone could should me how to run all 3 of the `WRK_TP_CD's` and instead of the values all falling in to the `BAL_AMT` field, I would like to see 3 separate fields in my select statement which will correspond to each one of the `WKR_TP_CD`.

In other words, My result set would have a field for `WKR_TP_CD 1, 2 and 3` with the appropriate values for each.

Thank you

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read, and to write.

Comment: Really, you should format your code and use JOIN instead of where clause, because it has advantages like: 1) easy to read; 2) easy to check, if your logic expressed in the appropriate way; 3) easy to edit

Comment: And one more thing is thanks to god for inventing WITH clause to split statement into subtables and not select from select from select

Comment: Jarlh and @astentx, thank you for your responses. Any idea on  how I would be able to  get WRK_TP_CD 1 2 3 in to my select as fields 1, 2 , and 3?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want 3 conditional fields which show the value of Bal_AMT, depending on a certain value of WRK_TP_CD. I'd try a case statement.

```
Select * 
from (select a.ID,
        a.DT,
        a.Bal_Desc,
        c.Bal_CD,
        case when WRK_TP_CD = '1' then c.Bal_AMT else null end as Bal_AMT_1,
        case when WRK_TP_CD = '2' then c.Bal_AMT else null end as Bal_AMT_2,
        case when WRK_TP_CD = '3' then c.Bal_AMT else null end as Bal_AMT_3,
        ROW NUMBER () Over (partition by b.ID order by b.PRD_ID desc, b.event desc) as RNUM
    FROM TBL_A a, TBL_B b, TBL_C c, TBL_D d
    where a.ID = B.ID
        and a.DT = b. DT
        and c.CD = d.CD
        and a.ID = C.ID
        and a.DT = c.DT
        and a.DT = 10222020
        and cn_dt is null
        and ev_cd = 'X'
        and PGM_CD = 'X'
        and WRK_TP_CD in ('1', '2', '3'))
Where rnum = 1;
```